# Combine rows in SQL On Join

Tags: sql, join

I want to combine pairs of rows into two columns. 
Currently, I am able to combine them into two columns, but I want to remove the instances where if the left column is 'A', then 'A' does not also appear in the right side. Essentially I have double the rows that I should.

Also, I read about using pivot, but could not get that to work.

```
Select t1.ID, concat(t1.Notes,' ' + t2.Notes) as Notes, t1.Flag, t2.ID as Old_ID
From mytable as t1
Left outer Join mytable as t2
    On ( t1.Flag = t2.Flag and t1.ID != t2.ID)
where t1.Notes is not null
```

Data:

```
ID |   NOTES | Flag
A       YES     1
B       YES     2
C       YES     3
D       YES     4
```

Current Output:

```
ID |   NOTES   | Flag | Old_ID
A     YES YES      1     B
C     YES YES      3     D
B     YES YES      2     A
D     YES YES      4     C
```

Expected Output:

```
ID |   NOTES   | Flag | Old_ID
A     YES YES     1      C
B     YES YES     2      D
```

Comment: t1 and t2 are the same, so how does `old_id` not equal `ID`?

Comment: I'm using MS SQL @JonathanAllen

Comment: That was my attempt to fix the issue. Without it, it doubles the output (2 rows of A, B, C, D) @JoseRodrigues

Comment: id and old_id actually reference two different data-sets (same table, aliased). Joining a table against itself is not uncommon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to your where clause

```
WHERE
    t1.Id < t2.Id
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Can't believe I did't think to just do that.

Answer (score 0):

## There's no way to determine which is the 'OLD' entry

```
A     YES YES      1     B  - which takes precidence?
B     YES YES      2     A
```

## You must define some critera by which to prioritize one entry over the other.

```
SELECT
    t1.ID,
    concat(t1.Notes,' ' + t2.Notes) AS Notes,
    t1.Flag,
    t2.ID AS Old_ID
FROM mytable AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable AS t2
    ON ( t1.Flag = t2.Flag AND t1.ID != t2.ID)
WHERE
    t1.Notes IS NOT NULL
    AND t1.id NOT IN (
        SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable GROUP BY Flag
    )
```